# how to import DefinitelyTyped to grunt-ts without an internet connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gruntjs, definitelytyped

I've download grunt-ts and DefinitelyTyped  library.
I try to compile the .ts files with grunt-ts.
The problem is that in the code there are nodeJS' "require" calls,and other node's function calls...
grunt-ts throws errors and the compile process does not proceed further.
I tried to use DefinitelyTyped  , my problem is that grunt-ts looks for it on github, but I usually work with an offline environment.
In the computer there is DefinitelyTyped files , but for some reason, grunt-ts doesn't look for it.
Can anyone help me direct grunt-ts to load those locally-placed definition files before it tries to compile the script?Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you prepare your entire project in an online environment - install `grunt-ts`, etc. - and then copy the entire project up to your offline environment.

Comment: Sorry, this is extremely impossible. I can transfer files into the environment, but I can't connect it to any network.

Comment: Can you transfer the entire project - including `node_modules`, etc.? It would be the simplest solution, I think.